# Rails clear_helpers only for specific controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails project at the moment, and I'm building a view using json_builder to use with the Layar API like so:

```
layer "Layer name"
errorString "ok"
errorCode 0
hotspots @inspections do |inspection|
    id inspection.slug
    anchor do
        geolocation do
            lat inspection.lat
            lon inspection.lng
        end
    end
    text do
        title inspection.name
        description "#{inspection.rating} out of 5"
        imageURL "http://my-url.com/assets/rating#{inspection.rating}.png"
    end
end
```

However, when I load this view in my browser, the `title` part of my JSON doesn't appear. I've managed to narrow this down to a helper method in my `layout_helper` file (I've been using nifty-generators), also named `title`. As I don't need this helper, is there any way of running `clear_helpers` for this particular controller action only? Or is there a neater way of doing this? (I'm pretty new to Rails, as you can probably tell!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up renaming the problematic helper method to `pagetitle` and changing my views. Sometimes the simplest solutions are easiest!

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be able to do the following in your controller:

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  helper :layout, :except => :show # Or whatever action you want to skip here
```

**Edit:**

So apparently Rails doesn't support that on the helper method, unlike all the similar methods. Unfortunately there doesn't actually seem to be a way to change which helpers are loaded per action. One idea I'm toying with is forcibly unregistering specific helpers per controller action, but it's not pretty.

Relevant API docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html

Comment: No dice unfortunately. I get the error `helper must be a String, Symbol, or Module`. If I leave out the :except bit it works, but obviously that helper is loaded on the action that I want to skip

Comment: Right, OK. I've nailed it now. Just renamed the helper method to something else! Sometimes the simplest solutions are the easiest! :)

Comment: Great! Updated my answer to point out why it doesn't work, but you should add and accept your own answer :)